# How to convert a real number to a string only in the original length?

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion, precision-and-accuracy

Example: I have this number

```
num = 2.9525730420542016*10^1798
(* 2.952573042054202*10^1798 *)
```

If I want to convert it to a string, I don't get "2.952573042054202*10^1798" but

```
ToString[num, InputForm]
(* "2.9525730420542015686180548`15.954589770191005*^1798" *)
```

How to get

```
"2.952573042054202*10^1798"
```

as string back ?

To explain this question: I have a 1.5 GB file with several million such numbers. I need to do some recalculation and save it to a file again. However, if I save the resulting values (using Write [...]), a file more than twice the size will be created. The accuracy of the input numbers is about 17 digits, so the values in the new file cannot be more accurate. The other decimal places are meaningless, so I need to trim them.

Comment: You could take the logarithm and then store them in binary format, which would take only 8 bytes per number and avoid all such issues. I'm suggesting storing the logarithm because your number overflows the standard double-precision format.

Comment: That's a good idea if I stayed inside Mathematica. But I need to have the output in text format so that it is easy to read in another program.

Comment: Actually binary numbers can be read in any program, thanks to the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Comment: Please stay with the original question. How to remove redundant digits from numbers obtained with N [...], resp. how to save really only in the specified accuracy, without extra digits?

Comment: You might be interested in `MantissaExponent[]`.

Comment: `"0." <> ToString[ 
  FromDigits[ RealDigits[ MantissaExponent[num][[1]]][[1]]]] <> "*10^" <>
  ToString[ MantissaExponent[num][[2]]]` solves my problem, thanks! But wouldn't it be easier?

Comment: `ToString[StandardForm@num, StandardForm]`?

Comment: @kglr: Not! After copying, I'll get out of it `"\!\(\*TagBox[FormBox[\"2.9525730420542015686180548`15.\
954589770191005*^1798\",StandardForm],StandardForm,Editable->True]\)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you satisfied with this form (without 10^)?

```
num = 2.9525730420542016*10^1798;

$NumberMarks = False; ToString[num, InputForm]

(*   2.9525730420542016*^1798   *)
```

Comment: This method is best! Thank you.

Comment: Great! I don't even have to convert an array of real numbers to the strings. I can immediately write the whole array as N[array, 17] and nothing unnecessary will be saved. One magic word "$NumberMarks" is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

The following function seems to do what you want

```
realToString[x_Real] := StringReplace[ToString[x,InputForm],
   StringExpression[a__~~"`"~~__~~"*^"~~b__]->a~~"*^"~~b];
```

For example try

```
FullForm[realToString@
     2.9525730420542015686180548`15.954589770191005*^1798]
```

which returns

```
"2.9525730420542015686180548*^1798"
```

If you want to limit the number of decimal digits then try

```
realToString[x_Real, nd_Integer:18] := Module[{a, b, ab=
  First[List@@StringReplace[ToString[x, InputForm],
  StringExpression[a__~~"`"~~__~~"*^"~~b__] -> {a ,b}]]},
  {a, b}=ab; StringTake[a, Min[StringLength@a, nd+1]]~~"*^"~~b];
```

For an example of this try

```
FullForm[realToString[
 2.9525730420542015686180548`15.954589770191005*^1798, 4]]
```

which returns

```
"2.952*^1798"
```

There are other ways to get Mathematica to do what you want,
but this approach is more user programmable in my opinion.

Comment: This is usable, but there are still 8-9 digits left, which are not valid and unnecessarily increase the size of the output file.

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec Thanks for your comment! I have upgraded my function which can now lmit the number of digits.

Answer (score 2):

Convert with [`CForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm.html), apply `ToString`, then replace "e" with "*10^". We have:

```
num = 2.9525730420542016*10^1798;
```

`CForm[num]` displays "2.952573042054202e1798", and we can get a string with:

```
StringReplace["e"->"*10^"][ToString@CForm@num]
```

> `2.952573042054202*10^1798`

For a list of values, make a list of strings with:

```
list = {num, num/1*^100, 2 num};
StringReplace["e"->"*10^"][ToString/@CForm/@list]
```

> `{2.952573042054202*10^1798, 2.952573042054202*10^1698, 5.905146084108403*10^1798}`